# Jbuilder Partial With Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials, jbuilder

I am attempting to render a partial jbuilder file using the below

```
json.(@request, :id)

json.profile do
    json.partial! partial: 'users/user_reduced', user: @request.user
end
```

the partial is below (users/_user_reduced.json.jbuilder)

```
json.(user, :id, :name, :sex)
```

However, I get the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0x007fe4ebc91878>:0x007fe4ebe599f8>):
```

It's as if the local user variable is not being set. What is the syntax for setting a local variable to a jbuilder partial path?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have tried to fix this for hours, and found, finally, that the syntax (thought listed on the jbuilder readme) above does not work. You must format your partials like the below:

```
json.partial! 'partials/partial_path', locals: {local_var: my_local_var}
```

So in my case, it would be:

```
json.(@request, :id)

json.profile do
    json.partial! partial: 'users/user_reduced', locals: {user: @request.user}
end
```

Comment: There's a shortcut: `json.profile do json.partial! 'users/user_reduced', user: @request.user'

Comment: It's not necessary to include partial: or locals:

Comment: but if you need to pass more variables, this shortcut not works. Example: 
`json.partial! partial: 'users/user_reduced', locals: { user: @request.user, other: 'value' }`